# Why is my jquery selector not working inside this google maps function?

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-3

With the [addDomListener](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events#DomEvents) I am trying to run a function when I hover over an element on my page. This works when I select the object with getElementById:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('myID'), 'mouseover', mouseoverListener);
```

But it doesn't work when I try using a jQuery selector:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener($('#myID'), 'mouseover', mouseoverListener);
```

I thought, perhaps the Google API isn't let me run jQuery or I haven't loaded it, but if I do something like:

```
$('#myID').append('1');
```

That works just fine and I get '1' inside #myID.

What am I missing and why isn't the selector work in a way that seems logical to me it would?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google API `addDomListener` expects a DOM node, not a jQuery object, use this:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener($('#myID')[0], 'mouseover', mouseoverListener);
```